# Using FTP with NSURL

Tags: cocoa, macos

I want to write a cocoa application which downloads a file using ftp. I read about the NSURL class which has "NSURLHandle FTP Property Keys". I want to know how do I make use of these constants to provide username and password to the ftp site.

Answer (score 5):

NSURLHandle is deprecated and has been for a while. Please use NSURLConnection or NSURLDownload instead. Either create one of these objects with a URL like this:

ftp://user:password@ftp.example.com/foo/bar.zip

Or, implement the authentication delegate method and pass in a standard URL:

ftp://ftp.example.com/foo/bar.zip

If you need to do anything more complicated than downloading a file, I suggest you look at [ConnectionKit](http://opensource.utr-software.com/connection/download.html) which provides full FTP connection support.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried inserting the username and password in the URL? Like:

```
ftp://user:pass@ftp.somewhere.com/path/to/file
```

If not you'll probably find what you need in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html).